# Could not find a part of the path excel error

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

I want to bind a `datatable` to `excel`. I have written the below code for that

```
public void ExportExcel()
{
   string str_lwpc_query = string.Empty;
   str_lwpc_query = "select company_name 'COMPANY NAME',Deputed_Company_Name 'DEPUTED COMPANY NAME',emp_card_no 'EMP CODE',emp_name 'EMPLOYEE NAME',LWP,'' Remarks,  " +
                    "Adj_Days Gain_Loss_LOP_Days, VAL_DAY LOP_Days_Desc, month, year from XXACL_EMP_INFO_LWP_OTDAYS_HRS_V " +
                     "where emp_type='C' and month = '3' and year = '2015'";

     DataTable Dt_lwpc = new DataTable();
     //DT_Overdue.TableName = "Daily Lead";
     Dt_lwpc = CF.ExecuteDT(str_lwpc_query);
     DataSet DS_lwpc = new DataSet();
     DS_lwpc.Tables.Add(Dt_lwpc);
     DS_lwpc.Tables[0].TableName = "Employee loss of pay for consultant Details";
     ExcelLibrary.DataSetHelper.CreateWorkbook("~/Attachment/Employee_lwpc_Details.xls", DS_lwpc);

}
```

but I am getting error as

> Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\DevServer\10.0\~\Attachment\Employee_lwpc_Details.xls'.

at last line. I don't know why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User `Server.MapPath` and get the directory relative to where your site is running from.

```
var directory = Server.MapPath("~/Attachment/");
ExcelLibrary.DataSetHelper.CreateWorkbook(directory + "Employee_lwpc_Details.xls", DS_lwpc);
```

This assumes the Attachment directory exists, otherwise you may need to create it.

Comment: Ask a new question, but it is likely to get closed as its not aprogramming question :)